# How to check if web app manifest exists via browser neutral methods?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

Is there a way of checking if a valid manifest.json exists and is being used as the app manifest, possibly with meta tags or something? The scenario I am in is needing to roll out progressive web app features on a case by case basis, rather than across the entirety of my app, and I need some kind of conditional logic to test for manifest.json existence to prevent errors later down the line.

Ive toyed with checking for the file manually using GET, but due to the specific and complex structure of the app it would be a lot more prudent if I could somehow just check if it exists using a different method. I would like to avoid jQuery if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
async function doesManifestExistForCurrentPage() {
  const manifestElement = document.querySelector('link[rel="manifest"]');
  if (!manifestElement) {
    return false;
  }
  const manifestUrl = manifestElement.getAttribute('href');
  if (!manifestElement) {
    return false;
  }

  // You could stop here and just return true.
  // If you want to actually see if the manifest file exists on the
  // server, use the following code:
  try {
    const manifestResponse = await fetch(manifestUrl);
    // .ok will be true if fetch() returned a HTTP 2xx response,
    // and false otherwise.
    return manifestResponse.ok;
  } catch (error) {
    // Or return true?
    // Depends on how you want to handle network failures.
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasAppManifest() {
    return document.querySelector('link[rel="manifest"]') ? true : false;
}
```